# Find all images whose source attribute value ends with some string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can one find all images whose source ends with for example "xyz.jpg"?

Using jQuery?

When I do:  `jQuery("img[src$='xyz.jpg']")` what am I getting back?
Is this an array-like thing or not? I am confused.

Seems like I am getting a single object. How can I get all such objects?

Comment: You're getting a jQuery collection back; what's the problem you're having with your code? Does it return anything, does it not work, in what way is your problem a problem? Where's your "*[mcve]*" code?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/

Comment: JPQ? You mean JPG??? `console.log(jQuery("img[src$='xyz.jpg']"))` and even easier to test: `console.log(jQuery("img[src$='xyz.jpg']").length)`

Comment: Is the typo in the selector just in your question `xyz.jpq` or is that copied from your source code? Should be `jpg` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('.some-selector')` (or `$('.some-selector')`) returns a jQuery object (https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery).

A jQuery objects behaves very much like an array of DOM elements. It has a `length` property and you can access these elements by index (`$('.some-selector')[0]`), but it is **not** a true array, and you won't find the common Array methods on this object.

So yes it return a *single* jQuery object, but that object might consist of zero, one or multiple DOM elements that matched your selector.

When you access the DOM elements in the jQuery collection you get "raw" DOM elements, i.e. you cannot use jQuery methods on them. Typically you would use jQuery methods on the entire collection, or rewrap individual elements in jQuery.

Comment: OK... thanks, So the object I get back, it's always an array-like thing, right? What about its elements, are they also wrapped in a jQuery object, or do I need to wrap them myself? Maybe that's my problem.

Comment: @peter.petrov no, it's not an Array-like thing. it's a jQuery Object. You can access the internal Array with your Elements by the jQuery provided methods (almost all of them) like i.e: .get() .each() .prop() .css() etc etc etc

Comment: Yeah, seems that was my problem. The elements inside the array-like object are not wrapped. I wrap them myself and the problem is gone.

Comment: @peter.petrov you don't need to wrap anything. They are already wrapped.

Comment: No, no ... Yes, I know, by array like I mean, I can loop through it and so on. The thing is: are the elements inside also jQuery objects?

Comment: But they were saying: "no attr method found" or something... Before I wrapped them myself.

Comment: Say you have : `$(div).each(function(i, el) {`  than yes, either `$(this)` or using `$(el)` Use `console.dir(this)` or `console.dir($(this))` or rather `console.log(this.constructor)` etc, to get a clue.

Comment: Once you have a jquery collection `$("img")` you do "things" with that collection.  Depending on what you do, depends on whether it's another jquery collection or a DOM element.  It can be confusing.   eg `$("img").hide()` affects all img.   `$("img").first()` is still a jquery object,  `$("img").each(function() { this...` `this` will be a DOM element, so will need to be re-wrapped:  `$(this).hide()`

Comment: I don't do `something.foreach`, I just loop through it by using a plain for cycle. In that case, do I need to wrap myself or not?

Comment: If you get `attr is not a function` then you probably have a DOM node.   Note there are quite a few functions that exist in both jquery and (now) javascript, eg `.closest` and `.submit` which *work differently* so you *must* know if you have a jquery object or a DOM node.

Comment: "plain `for`" - there's 5 or 6 (didn't count them) different "plain for" loops, so will depend on which one...  eg `for (var i in $("img"))` will cycle the properties/functions of a jquery collection.  If you have the construct `$(..)[i]` then it will be a DOM element.

Comment: Yes, I use the latter, the simple old `for arr[i]` So that explains it all. In that case I need to wrap myself, right? Thanks a lot. And sorry my my unclear ask. I am not good at JavaScript/jQuery, I have some basic ideas only.